# How to disable resubmit of data on refresh or reload of the page

Tags: jsp, url, struts2, action

I have a JSP page which has a button, on click of this button an action is performed which does some database update and after successful update the user is navigated to some another page with ending url `...\resultpage.action`.

When I reload the navigated page `resultpage.jsp`, the action is called again which updates the database again, which is not desirable.

I want that if a user reloads this page, the page should be refreshed and no action class should be called which updates the database.

How to achieve it? Also if there is any means that after loading the page its url should be changed?

Answer (score 0):

More often than not I will create a result type other than the standard "success" in order to avoid the scenario of resubmitting a form through page refresh. There may be other ways to do it, but the easiest way that I've found is result type redirectAction that goes back to the same action on a successful database update.

if you use annotations it would look something like this:

```
@Results({
    @Result(name = "success", location = "/WEB-INF/content/registration/index.jsp"),
    @Result(name = "refresh", type = "redirectAction", location = "register")
})
```

The "refresh" result would be returned on a successful (database update) post action whereas "success" is used for display type actions.